# How can i view content from sqlite database

Tags: android, android-sqlite, data-retrieval

I have done a program for insert and retrieve data from android sqlite database..

inserting is working properly. but the viewing data does not take place.
my code is attached below. please help me with the below code

```
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ViewActivity extends Activity  {
    SQLiteDatabase myDB = null;
    String TableName = "LIST";
    String Data = "";


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view);
    }
    public void show1(View v) { 

          Cursor c = myDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM  LIST", null);

            int Column1 = c.getColumnIndex("Name");
            int Column2 = c.getColumnIndex("Address");
            int Column3 = c.getColumnIndex("Phone");

            c.moveToFirst();

            if (c != null) {

                do {
                    String Name = c.getString(Column1);
                    String Address = c.getString(Column2);
                    String Phone = c.getString(Column3);
                    Data = Data + Name + "\t\t" + Address + "\n\n" + Phone + "\n\n";

                } while (c.moveToNext());
            }

            TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.show1);; // creating Text View to show data in the app
           tv.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
           tv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.b);
            tv.setTextSize(18F);
            tv.setText("\n"+"Name \t| Address \n \t| Phone \n ----------------------\n");
           setContentView(tv);  // set created text view as Content View 

        }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your table and column names, seems to be always the usual issue. A question, if you are appending the result in the Data String why are you not using it to be shown on your Activity? Is the Data String empty after the do while block?

Second, you should try to use the Data Access Object pattern http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object your code will be more maintanable and tidy.

Comment: Data String is empty when you end the do/while?

Comment: when clicking on view button always shows unfortunately stopped working error

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer.. it seems simple

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
     SQLiteDatabase db;
      TextView tv;
      EditText et1,et2,et3;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      //initialize all view objects
        tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        et1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        et2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        et3=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);

      //create database if not already exist
        db= openOrCreateDatabase("Anoop", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        //create new table if not already exist
        db.execSQL("create table if not exists mytable(name varchar, address varchar,phone varchar)");
        }
        //This method will call on when we click on insert button
        public void insert(View v)
        {
         String name=et1.getText().toString();
         String address=et2.getText().toString();
         String phone=et3.getText().toString();
         et1.setText("");
         et2.setText("");
         et3.setText("");
         //insert data into able
         db.execSQL("insert into mytable values('"+name+"','"+address+"','"+phone+"')");
        //display Toast
        Toast.makeText(this, "values inserted successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }
        //This method will call when we click on display button
        public void display(View v)
        {
        //use cursor to keep all data
        //cursor can keep data of any data type
        Cursor c=db.rawQuery("select * from mytable", null);
        tv.setText("");
        //move cursor to first position
        c.moveToFirst();
        //fetch all data one by one
        do
        {
         //we can use c.getString(0) here
         //or we can get data using column index
         String name=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name"));
         /*String address=c.getString(1);
         String phone=c.getString(2);*/
         String address=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("address"));
         String phone=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("phone"));
         //display on text view
         tv.append("Name:"+name+"  Address:"+address+"   Phone:"+phone+"\n");
         //move next position until end of the data
        }while(c.moveToNext());
       }
     }
```